# Pipes in HTML tags?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

Is it possible to use pipes in HTML tags?

```
<h1 [innerHTML]="date ? date | date : '<i>Date not set</i>'"></h1>
```

If `date` is defined the date with the date-pipe should be display. Otherwise `Date not set` should be displayed.

The code above doesn't work.

What is the best way to achieve this?

EDIT

Thanks to @Pankaj Parkar

The solution is

```
<h1 [innerHTML]="date ? (date | date) : '<i>Date not set</i>'"></h1>
```

I tried with `{{ }}` and `[[ ]]` but only `( )` works.

Comment: `<h1 *ngIf="date">{{date | date}}</h1><h1 *ngIf="!date"><i>Date not set</i></h1>`

Comment: I guess you only need to wrap pipe expression in brackets like `[innerHTML]="date ? (date | date) : '<i>Date not set</i>'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Pankaj Parkar` is right!

Use it like this:

`<h1 [innerHTML]="date ? (date | date) : '<i>Date not set</i>'"></h1>`